# rails app won't run on new machine - rvm, bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am trying to set up a new development machine. We have a rails 3.0.3 app, using (obviously) bundler and rvm. We are sharing the .rvmrc through git. it is:

```
rvm ree@tgr_r3
```

Here is the strange behaviour:

```
rvm gemset delete tgr_r3 (make sure the gemset is gone)
cd ..
cd tgr2/
gem install bundler
bundle install --without production
rails c
```

At this point it is working - I can select do things like User.last and get items from our dev database.

But... If I do this:

```
cd ..
cd tgr2/
rails c
```

I now get:

```
/Users/psmy/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@tgr_r3/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.7.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
Abort trap
```

What is going on here? I've tried this both with and without the Gemfile.lock from our git repo. Same result.
I have other Rails 3 apps (and Rails 2 apps) on this machine that are working.

Comment: Are you sure the executed `rails` is the one from your project? What if you do `./script/rails c` ? What is the difference between the first set of commands and the second? In both cases you are in `tgr2` directory, right?

Comment: Try using the bundle exec command to ensure that the expected environment is used. e.g. `bundle exec rails c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. 
If I first do

```
rvm use ree --default
```

then the above process is fine. I think there was no default ruby for rvm and that was screwing up the compilation of native stuff. Or something. All I know is that it works now.